# What is a number class?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I’m reading a book on mathematics and I’m realy enjoing it. It had some mistakes but I think this may not be one. It explains a number class as follows:[image]
How can an ordinal number be equivalent to another? I believe misunderstood something.

Comment: The first infinite ordinal number $\omega$ is equivalent to $\omega +1 = \omega \cup \{\omega\}$, for example. A bijection $\omega + 1 \to  \omega$ is given by $\omega \mapsto 0$ and $n \mapsto n+1$ for all $ n < \omega$.

Comment: E.g., the ordinal numbers $\omega$, $\omega+1$, $\omega \cdot 2$, $\omega^2$, etc are all equivalent, in the sense that they are all in bijection with one another (countably infinite). On the other hand, $\omega_1$ (the first uncountable ordinal) is not equivalent to $\omega$, but *is* equivalent to $\omega_1+1$, $\omega_1 + \omega$, etc.

Comment: If an order type is a set with all sets that relate one to another one-to-one and are ordered equally the nature of the equivalency between two different ordinal numbers is the nature of it’s elements? It can’t be the order, right? We are assuming it is well ordered.

Comment: Which book are you reading? That seems like an incredibly outdated terminology and notation. I'd advise that you first read a newer book, understand the material, and then read this one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It appears to be *Fundamentals of Mathematics*, Vol. I, *Foundations of Mathematics: The Real Number System and Algebra*, a 1974 translation of the 1962 second edition of *Grundzüge der Mathematik*, sponsored by the German section of the International Commission for Mathematical Instruction; the first edition was in 1958. It was [uploaded to Scribd](https://www.scribd.com/document/317658760/Fundamentals-of-Mathematics-Vol-1-Foundations-of-Mathematics-the-Real-Number-System-and-Algebra) at some point.

Comment: @Brian: Definitely seems out of date.

Comment: Can you guys recommend me a book that is intuitive enough to an undergraduate?

Comment: What are you trying to learn? Set theory? Enderton has a nice book; Jech & Hrbacek gets a lot of good feedback; Just & Weese has a decent book; Halmos has a book on naive set theory, many like it, but I don't like it as much.

Comment: I’ll take a look at them. Thank you all! Could someone close the question (if this is how it works)?